# How to call methods from a C++ library in C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a vendor's DLL that is meant to be called from C++, but I need to call it from C#.

Using an app called PE Explorer I can see the list of exported methods in the DLL (call it Protocol.dll for now) and even get an 'Undecorated C++ Function' signature like this:

```
public: unsigned int __thiscall Myco::Protocol::tMultiThingClient::GetThings(char (* const)[16],unsigned int)
```

How do I use something like that in C#?  I know I use DllImport, I just don't know how to go from the signature above to a proper DllImport signature.

Total WAG:

```
[DllImport("Protocol.dll", EntryPoint="GetThings")]
public static extern void GetThings(ref string[], uint);
```

Is that even close? Is there a reference somewhere that translates between C++ declarations like `char (* const)[16]` and their C# equivalents?

Comment: This question is asked weekly on SO.  If you are calling a C++ member function you must use CallingConvention.ThisCall.  However every time someone asks this on SO, the answer is always "don't do this, write a C++/CLI wrapper." It is much much easier.

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/ is probably the best information available if you don't want to write your own wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a seperate project containing mixed assembly using C++ CLI. For this, you need to enable the CLR compiler switch in your project properties. Since, the project allows mixed assembly, you can call the C++ function, and also create a C# interface for your main program to call.

So, your main program will call the interface you implement inside your C++ CLI project, which will in turn call the C++ funtion inside the DLL.

Please beware of Marshalling and Thunking while you do this, if it applies to your system considerations.

Comment: I don't recommend using a mixed assembly (semms very ugly to me) if it is possible to solve the problem with correct marshalling.

Comment: @joe Where will `this` come from?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, do you know of a good tutorial or walk through for this? The C++ CLI route does seem a bit daunting to newbees.

Comment: @user I don't know of one. C++/CLI is like the wild west.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, is C++ CLI still the most preferred means to interop? I have not kept up with the updates and wonder if Microsoft now recommends some other way over C++ CLI to achieve native managed interop?

Comment: @user It depends. In this case, it's hard to see an alternative because the interface is a C++ OOP interface. If p/invoke is possible it can make deployment easier. C++/CLI probably has the best perf.